# With wicket where does hibernate.cfg.xml file go?

Tags: hibernate, wicket

I'm new to Wicket and Hibernate and can't get past the "org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found" error. I've put that file in every location imagineable but I'm still stuck. Where exactly does that file go and/or am I missing a wicket file config setting somewhere?

Comment: The fact that you are using wicket has nothing to do with hibernate. Put the hibernate.cfg.xml inside the classpath (e.g. the src directory) as Kiran already says.

Comment: Paste some code! If you create the SessionFactory by hand (that is, you create a Configuration, populate its properties and build the factory from that), paste this creation code.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure hibernate.cfg.xml file placed in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting with Wicket and Hibernate, you may be interested in the [Databinder toolkit](http://databinder.net).

Answer (score 0):

I'd place the hibernate,cfg.xml in the /WEB-INF folder of your application.

Answer (score 0):

the common form to connect that technologies is with springframework, take  a look http://wicketinaction.com/2009/06/wicketspringhibernate-configuration/

and also springframework help you with  lazy load exception, and transaction management